# Using Task.FromResult to implicitly convert a Task<T> to a Task<X> where T : X?

Tags: c#, inheritance, task

```
Task<IDictionary<double, double>> GetTaskDict()
{
     return Task.FromResult(new Dictionary<double, double> () );
}
```

This code does not compile because we can not convert between Task<Dictionary<double, double>> to Task<IDictionary<double, double>>. Why does this not work, and is it possible to make this type of call work? This opposed to a method like this which compiles

```
IDictionary<double, double> GetTaskDict()
{
     return new Dictionary<double, double> ();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```cs
return Task.FromResult<IDictionary<double, double>>(new Dictionary<double, double>());
```

This is because `Task<T>` is not covariant, so a `Task<Foo>` is not interchangeable with a `Task<IFoo>` even if `Foo : IFoo`.

You may also wish to consider using `ValueTask<T>` if you're going to have lots of results which are available synchronously - it is significantly cheaper in that scenario. You can even use the implicit `new()` usage in that scenario:

```cs
ValueTask<IDictionary<double, double>> GetTaskDict()
{
    return new(new Dictionary<double, double>());
}
```

(here, `new(...)` is interpreted as `new ValueTask<IDictionary<double, double>>(...)` from the declared return-type of the method)

Comment: This is exactly the explanation I was looking for, and I didn't know about ValueTask<T>. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**Suppose it *were* possible.**

Then someone could do this:

```cs
Task<IDictionary<double, double>> myTaskDict = new Task<Dictionary<double, double>>();

Task.SetResult(myIDictionaryWhichIsNotActuallyADictionary);
```

In other words, as @MarcGravell has said, `Task` is not covariant, and for very good reason.

---

**You *can* specify the type explicitly like this though:**

```cs
Task<IDictionary<double, double>> GetTaskDict()
{
     return Task.FromResult<IDictionary<double, double>>(new Dictionary<double, double>());
}
```